# Insert a string to a string in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, string

I need to insert a string 'GMT' into

```
"2010-07-13T11:22:33-07:00"
```

before the last '-' (it could also be a '+')
the result should be

```
"2010-07-13T11:22:33GMT-07:00"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-rangeOfString_options_)  and [NSMutableString](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/replaceCharactersInRange:withString:) documentation.  I believe what you're looking for is something along the lines of the following (I haven't tested this code, but judging by the documentation it should work):

```
NSMutableString* date = @"2010-07-13T11:22:33-07:00";
NSRange r = [date rangeOfString:@"-" options:NSSearchBackwards];
[date replaceCharactersInRange: r withString: @"GMT-"];
```